# When does rules based classifier outperforms decision trees?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, decision-tree

Suppose I have an option to choose between making a Decision Tree and a rule based classifier, which one should I choose?
Assuming that the rule based classifier has mutually exclusive and exhaustive set of rules, then which one is preferable?
Is there some specific advantage/drawback of rule based classifier to help us decide if it should be preferred over Decision trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your data is already in categorical/sub-categorical form i.e. refined, then you can choose rule based else for more raw data you can choose tree based algos.